# Polymorphic (de-)serialization to specific type if field type is an interface with Jackson

Tags: spring, serialization, interface, jackson, polymorphism

I would like to de-/serialize based on an interface and I cannot change the classes because they are 3rd party (org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJson)

POJO:

```
public class Geofence {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String topic;
    private Date expiresOn;
    private Map<String, String> properties;
    private GeoJson geometry;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The geometry field could be `GeoJsonPolygon` or `GeoJsonPoint`.

I also added this MixIn class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GeoJsonPolygon.class, name = "Polygon"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GeoJsonPoint.class, name = "Point")})
public abstract class GeoJsonMixIn implements GeoJson{

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String getType() {
        return null;
    }

    @JsonProperty("coordinates")
    public Iterable<?> getCoordinates() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I try to deserialize an object (via a REST interface) like

```
{
    "expiresOn": "2017-01-01",
    "topic": "test",
    "properties": {
        "radius": 200
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.349997997283936,
          52.51448414445241
        ]
      }
}
```

I get this exception:

**Could not read document: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)**

On serialization I get:

**Failed to instantiate org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJson using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments**

Is this even possible? How can I achieve this?

Everything works, if I don't use polymorhpism - like if I change it to

```
    private GeoJsonPoint geometry;
```

and my GeoJson is actually a Point. So there apparently IS a suitable constructor etc.

Answer (score 2):

Probably is too late but I had the same exact problem as you and I figured out that you need to add a configuration on Spring to enable GeoJsonModule. So you need to create a Spring configuration class, if you don't have it already, and add this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoDbConfig {

    @Bean
    public Module registerGeoJsonModule(){
        return new GeoJsonModule();
    }
}
```

SpringMongoDbConfig is the class I created for editing Spring Configuration, choose what you prefer.

As you can see from the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/geo/GeoJsonModule.html) GeoJsonModule it's a specific class for serialization and deserialization. All other code with the Abstract class seems ok to me, it's the way to go.

Comment: That did it for me. Thank you. I had the same problem